# ib_insync - How to handle errors

Tags: ib-api, ib-insync

I moved from IB official API to ib_insync, and with the second one I don't see a way to handle errors like IB API. Is there any way in ib_insync to handle also the errors like this?

`def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):`

```
    if(errorCode == 502) or (errorCode == 504): 
        print("ERROR: Fallo de conexión - Comprobar sockets TWS")
        exit()
    elif(errorCode not in self.goodErrors): 
        print("Error {} {} {}".format(reqId,errorCode,errorString))
        #self.disconnect()

# Errores no importantes:
# - 2104: Market Data Farm OK
# - 2106: Historical Data Farm OK
# - 2158: Sec-Def Data Farm OK
goodErrors = (2104, 2106, 2158)`
```

This works for IBAPI but not in ib_insync

Answer (score 0):

Two steps. First, an error event handler function must be written. Second, it must be registered. Here are some snippets of my own code that may get you started. I wrote a Logger class for obvious reasons.

```
    def OnErrorEvent(self, aReqId:int, aErrorCode:int, aErrorString:str, aContract):
    logger:Logger.CLogger = Logger.CLogger(
        sys._getframe().f_code.co_name,
        "TWS API ERROR. aReqId", aReqId,
        "aErrorCode", aErrorCode,
        "aErrorString", aErrorString,
        "aContract", aContract)
```

Create your ib_insync object:

```
        self.iIbInsync = ib_insync.IB()

        # Callback registration
        self.iIbInsync.errorEvent          += self.OnErrorEvent
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey man thats helpful. I understand the idea but i dont succeed with creating a event handler. I attempted with Event class, but doesn't work because ib_insync uses that already. I'm trying to use your OnErrorEvent function, but i dont know how to manage the logger in the function.

Comment: Also I have a doubt, if you put `+= self.OnErrorEvent` you arent changing the standard output of the IB error, no? Its so extensive and i want to modify it completely

Comment: I guess the callback presents errors of IB and ib_insyc. It also presents errors that are just not errors, such as the datafarm for historic data is available. Further googling on "errorEvent ib_insync" gives you more code examples.

Comment: Yes I know those errors, i want to filter all by code like in IB official API. I have already search examples of handle functions but i didnt see any interesing, all are about only adding another error message to the standard error like I said `+= self.OnErrorEvent`. Do you have any doc or deeper examples of how to make a logger/handler?

Comment: I don't understand your question. With this `+=` instruction a callback function is registered to ib_insync. In my snippets, the registered callback is named `OnErrorEvent`. The callback function is executed when an error is encountered if it is registered. This callback function receives the error code as argument and therefore you can exit if `aErrorCode` is 502 like in your original question. There is no error message added, a callback is registered. I don't have further info.

Comment: Oh my bad, i'll explain that better with an example. I have the event function `def OnErrorEvent(self, aReqId:int, aErrorCode:int, aErrorString:str, aContract):
        print(str(aErrorCode) + ' AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA')` and registered it `self.errorEvent += self.OnErrorEvent`. The error output is `Error 321, reqId 12: Error al validar la solicitud.-'bS' : causa - (...) no se ajusta a la normativa del mercado.", errorCode=321)], advancedError='')
321 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA` and my goal is only output the OnErrorEvent function. And i see that `+=` is adding instead of removing the standard error.